# Occasional duplicate request using jmeter

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

I'm using JMeter 4.0 trying to create a stress test.  The purpose is to emulate the types of requests we receive in production, which is generally an array of requests of different types with a certain frequency and *occasionally* (1 in 1000) duplicate requests of the same type within milliseconds of each other.

I've managed to create a thread group emulating frequent requests of different types and a second thread group emulating duplicate requests (using synchronizing timer to ensure the requests fire off together).

I'm *almost* finished.  My only problem is that there is no relationship between the thread groups whatsoever.  If I wanted to perform a duplicate request once every 1000 requests, I'd need to know how long it takes to perform an average request (which is complicated by the fact that there are several request types) and calculate the time it would require for roughly 1000 requests to be made, and add an appropriate constant timer in the other thread group.

This isn't ideal.  I'll settle for this if I must, but I was hoping the bright minds of stackoverflow could shine some insight for my issue.

Some ideas I've had:

- Add a run counter which cycles every 1000 normal requests and once run counter hits 1000, I perform a second request (though it would be under the same thread and *after* I've received the response from the first).  Could this be made to work using a synchronized timer?
- Use a constant throughput timer with "all active threads (shared)" set whose samples per minutes is set to 1000.

Is there a better way still?  The actual requests are HTTP requests, though there are several steps prior in preparation of the message to send.  I'm already using a constant throughput timer in the first thread group (random service requests) to maintain a specific amount of requests per minute, so I'm not sure if adding a second constant throughput timer in the other thread group would create issues.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can add [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) with condition of 1 every 1000 threads

```
${__jexl3(${__threadNum} % 1000 == 0)}
```

and inside If Controller execute your duplicate HTTP Request

- [__threadNum](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) return current thread/user number

Comment: Thank you for your response!  Though by the nature of a HTTP request, doesn't it wait for the response before proceeding with the next?  I need both to happen simultaneously.  If there were a way to start an additional thread to launch the HTTP request, this could work.  Otherwise, I'm still stuck.  :(

Comment: @Neil put If before HTTP request and inside it (if true) launch both HTTP Requests, also check https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md